# trying to set numberOfRowsInSection with NSDictionary values

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary

I am trying to set up my uitableview for indexing, I have got number of sections working fine, now and the data is in the NSDictionary heres my output with nslog --->

```
Dictionary: {
    H =     (
        Honda,
        Honda,
        Honda,
        Honda,
        Honda,
        Honda,
        Honda
    );
    M =     (
        Mazda,
        Mazda,
        Mitsubishi,
        Mitsubishi,
        Mitsubishi,
        Mitsubishi,
        Mitsubishi,
        Mitsubishi
    );
    N =     (
        Nissan,
        Nissan,
        Nissan,
        Nissan,
        Nissan,
        Nissan,
        Nissan
    );
    T =     (
        Toyota,
        Toyota,
        Toyota
    );
```

I am now trying to set up my table like so

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [arraysByLetter count];
    //return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[arraysByLetter objectAtIndex:section] count];
    //return 1;
}
```

however I am getting a warning  **'NSMutableDictionary' may not respond to 'objectAtIndex:'** inside my numberOfRowsInSection delegate method... How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot index a dictionary as you would an array. You access dictionaries using keys. NSDictionary does provide two methods for getting arrays: allKeys and allValues.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if you want to organize the car makers alphabetically, you can get all the keys ([arraysByLetter allKeys]), sort them alphabetically, and then index into that sorted array. When you actually get the car makers' names you will then use objectForKey: to load the array of makers.

**Update:**
Assuming a sorted array named sortedLetters, you can change your numberOfRowsInSection to the following:

```
NSString *currentLetter = [sortedLetters objectAtIndex:section];
return [[arraysByLetter objectForKey:currentLetter] count];
```

You probably want to setup the sortedLetters array on initialization, unless it is dynamic.

Comment: I am trying to create a section index for uitableview scrolling.. Its such a major pain in the ars. I am working with one solution I have been showing but I am having trouble getting this part to work.

Comment: Okay, I understand exactly whats going on their just have to get my array of letters properly :) thanks, will let you know how I go.

Comment: Yep, got this to work! thank you very much! a whole weeks of struggle almost at an end :)

Answer (score 1):

The warning message is telling you exactly what the problem is: `arraysByLetter` is an instance of `NSMutableDictionary` not `NSArray` (or its subclass, `NSMutableArray`), and therefore doesn't respond to `NSArray` methods such as `objectAtIndex:`.

Instead, you should be using the `NSDictionary` method `objectForKey:`, and passing the letter of the alphabet that corresponds to the provided section number. You could use a `switch` statement or an array of strings to figure out which key to pick.

Comment: I get what your saying will try that now.

Comment: thanks for that I have done what you have said and now have the itableview working correctly.. just have to initalise the tableviewcells with the names now. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

objectAtIndex is an array method, not a dictionary method. The way I use dictionaries for table data sources is as so:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
{
NSArray *keys = [arraysByLetter allKeys];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveComapre:)];

return [[arraysByLetter objectForKey:[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section]] count];
}
```

The reason we have to sort is because allKeys appears in no particular order and can change.

Comment: Thankyou, I now have all my tbales set up (I.e. right amount of sections and cells per section. What I am trying to figure out now is how to set the uitableviewcell textlabel with NSDictionary values.. do you know how to do that?

Comment: Sure, you use the same sorting as before, but you grab the text by passing [[arraysByLetter objectForKey:[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you cannot use objectAtIndex on a dictionary. You need to first extract the objects on your dictionary using objectForKey on your dictionary and then create an array from those objects. Then you may use objectAtIndex on that array (array of array objects) and use count on the result. Or a simple allValues message to your dictionary would also suffice.

EDIT:

In your case if you need your first section to have seven rows (seven Hondas), create an array and place [dictionary allValues] as its content. Use that array inside your numberOfRowsInSection method like you do now with your dictionary.